# Meaning/Translation of a mantra video

Tags: mantras

I stumble upon [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIjX3dAHsxY) youtube video.

Can anyone explain or translate what is being said?

It is so **addictive** and **energising**...

Thanks & best regards from Portugal!

Answer (score 3):

The verses are basically repetition of a certain *Shiva Stotra* gradually increasing in tempo. The lyrics of which is,

> Shiva Shambho Hara Hara Shambho
>
> Bhava nasha Kailasa nivasa
>
> Parvati pate Harey Pashupatey
>
> (Hara) Gangadhara Shiva Gauripatey

The translation of which is,

> Lord Shiva, giver of good fortune, remover of fear and 
>   ego.
>
> Destroyer of the fear of life and death, resident of *Kailasa* (abode of Shiva).
>
> Lord of *Parvati* (Shiva's consort), destroyer of all sins, Lord of all beings
>
> Lord who wears the *Ganga* (river) in his hair, *Shiva*, Lord of *Gauri* (synonym for Parvati)

Comment: Much appreciated.